# how do i replace a fence post that was also used as a deck footing?

Tags: repair, deck, fence, post, footings

So I removed the old broken 4x4 post that was for the fence and deck.  I have the deck sitting on stone slab after I held it up with a jack.  It had two bolts that I had to cut out that are still in the holes for the deck framing so I cant put the new 4x4 post back in the same way to attach it back to the deck.  Any ideas on what to do?

Comment: Can you better explain what is at the bottom where the new post would go?  Maybe add a photo?  I am trying to understand what is there to fasten to.

Comment: Drill new holes?

Answer (score 2):

Use a sledgehammer and a large punch to drive out the old bolts. For one-time use, a spike just smaller in diameter than the bolts, with the tip cut off flat may work well-enough at a lower cost, if you don't have a large punch on hand.